# How to rotate a Tswitch

Tags: rotating, pst-circ

How can I rotate a Tswitch (SPDT) 90 degrees? I'm out of answers (my Herbert Voss Bible is clueless).

The following code gives me a vertical switch but I need it to be horizontal.

Thanks,

JL

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-circ}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(3,3)
  \pnode(1,1){X}
  \pnode(2,3){Y}
  \pnode(1,3){Z}
  \Tswitch[tripolestyle=left](Z)(Y)(X){}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `\rput{90}{...\Tswitch...}`?